# Why the phpinfo() function gives wrong result when one or more of the numerical constants bitwise values are passed as arguments?

Tags: function, constants, php, bitwise-or

I'm using **PHP 7.2.8**

I executed below code :

```
<?php
  phpinfo(2 | 8); //Bitwise OR operator is used
?>
```

Above code worked fine and give me the expected result.

Then I tried to pass the numerical constants bitwise values as arguments i.e. binary equivalents of numbers 2 and 8 as arguments. Please see the below code :

```
<?php
  phpinfo(00000010 | 1000000); //Bitwise OR operator is used
?>
```

I got unexpected output of above code(i.e. the second one where bitwise values of numerical constants are passed).

Why so?

Please refer [This Link](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php#refsect1-function.phpinfo-parameters) for the information of description on arguments to be passed to the `phpinfo()` function and the meaning of each and every numerical constants to be passed.

Please let me know where I'm making a mistake? I'm just trying to execute the code as described in the manual text.

Thank You.

Comment: The only difference between the output is that the 2nd one has the license information.

Comment: Why are you using numeric values in the first place, instead of the named constants?

Comment: @Barmar : Thanks for your comment. I used the numeric values only after referring the 'phpinfo() Example' given on the PHP Manual description page of phpinfo() function. In this example they have demonstrated that phpinfo(INFO_MODULES); and phpinfo(8); yield identical results. So, I tried using corresponding numerical values of constants. Is such usage treated as invalid according to PHP standards of coding? Please guide me in this regard. I'm waiting keenly for your response on this doubt of mine.

Comment: It's bad practice by *any* standards of coding. It's never a good idea to hard-code magic numbers. If someone is reading the code, how are they supposed to know what those numbers represent? They'd have to search for it in the documentation, when you could make it easy by just using the named constant.

Comment: @Barmar : Thanks for your valuable suggestion sir. I will always keep this thing in my mind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To express numbers in binary in PHP, you must use the prefix `0b` (e.g, `0b00000010`).

Without that prefix, these numbers are being interpreted in a way you didn't intend. `00000010` is interpreted as the octal representation of 8, and `1000000` is being read as one million, in decimal.